# read from a text file, tally the results and print them out (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to gather a list from a .txt file, tally the results and then print them out like this

```
Bones found:
Ankylosaurus: 3
Pachycephalosaurus: 1   
Tyrannosaurus Rex: 1
Struthiomimus: 2
```

An eample of the dot text file is

```
Ankylosaurus
Pachycephalosaurus
Ankylosaurus
Tyrannosaurus Rex
Ankylosaurus
Struthiomimus
Struthiomimus
```

My current code pulls all the names from the .txt file, except im completely stuck from there

```
frequency = {}
for line in open('bones.txt'):
  bones = line.split()
  print(bones)
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

with open(filename) as infile:    #Open File
    for line in infile:           #Iterate Each Line
        d[line.strip()] += 1

print("Bones found:")        
for k, v in d.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```

**Output:**

```
Bones found:
Struthiomimus: 2
Pachycephalosaurus: 1
Ankylosaurus: 3
Tyrannosaurus Rex: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Store each line as a dictionary key (initialized to 0 if line isn't in dict) and increment the value:

```
frequency = {}
for line in open('bones.txt'):
  if line not in frequency:
    frequency[line] = 0

  frequency[line] += 1

for k, v in frequency.items():
  print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

Comment: Hey, that doesnt seem to be working, its printing is adding numbers to the end for the very last one? - Ankylosaurus
3:
Pachycephalosaurus
1:
Tyrannosaurus Rex
1:
Struthiomimus
1:
Struthiomimus1:

Comment: After the 'for' line just add 'line = line.rstrip()' it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Counter function from collections library to get this.

```
from collections import Counter
f=open('bones.txt','r')
ls=f.readlines()
s=dict(Counter(ls))

for k in s.keys():
    print ('{}:{}'.format(k,s[k]))
```